# Problema con la generación del jar en proyecto Java

Tags: java, jar

Antes que todo aclarar, si se me genera la aplicación, esta contiene un JDesktopPane, desde el cual se llaman los elementos y en general estos no funcionan. Resulta que este proyecto no era mío desde un inicio, lo descargue como plantilla y lo empecé a editar, la cosa es que todas las ventanas que no cree yo no las carga el jar, les hice muchas ediciones a todas en general, pero pareciera que algo nulifica su referencia al extrapolarse a archivo jar, es como si no estuviesen incluidas en el jar, pero si se abren cuando lo ejecuto directamente en netbeans. Además me abre solo una ventana y es una que cree de cero, osea sin influencia del código anterior. El error que me salta dice: "Error Null.Pointer.Exception", la verdad no entiendo que puede estar faltando, evidentemente hay una falta de archivos que no se están encontrando, pero no sé debido a que.
Probé a crear un jar y luego probé a crear un exe de instalación y ninguna de las dos opciones me ayudó a que reconociera de algún modo los paquetes. Soy bastante nuevo en la creación de ejecutables.
¿Alguna idea?

Comment: has probado en crearlo desde netbeans

Comment: Lee lo que puse, si lo dije